# Nested modules in Rails breaking table_name_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I'm trying to use nested module/class definitions consistently in a Rails app, rather than the compact (`::`) syntax. However, it doesn't always load the module file itself, which contains the `table_name_prefix`.

Using Rails 4.1.8 on Ruby 2.1.1...

```
rails new my_app
...
rails g scaffold User
rails g scaffold Blog::Post
```

This creates `app/models/blog.rb`:

```
module Blog
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'blog_'
  end
end
```

There seem to be many ways of accidentally preventing Rails from auto-loading `blog.rb`. The simplest example is via the helpers.

Change `app/helpers/blog/posts_helper.rb` from:

```
module Blog::PostsHelper
end
```

to:

```
module Blog
  module PostsHelper
  end
end
```

Launch the server, visit `/users` and then visit `/blog/posts`:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
```

Similar problems can occur elsewhere, such as in the model tests. It's not limited to the helpers.

What's the best way of resolving this? Explicitly loading `blog.rb` and any other namespace modules?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the issue - thanks Anthony.  I'd create an issue over on github and see what the team says.

Comment: Perhaps... though I'm more looking for the best way of making sure `blog.rb` gets loaded, rather than suggesting a change to Rails. It's clearly not a problem many people have run into...

Comment: This no longer seems to be a problem in Rails 6 (zeitwerk autoloader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, which doesn't rely on autoloading, is to set the models to inherit from the following, instead of from `ActiveRecord::Base` directly:

```
class CustomActiveRecordBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # If no table name prefix has been defined, include the namespace/module as
  # table name prefix, e.g., Blog:: -> blog_
  def self.table_name
    # If a table_name_prefix has been defined, follow default behaviour
    return super if full_table_name_prefix.present?

    # Find the prefix, e.g., Blog::Post -> 'blog', User -> ''
    prefix = model_name.name.deconstantize.underscore

    # If no prefix, follow default behaviour
    return super unless prefix.present?

    # Otherwise add the prefix with an underscore
    "#{prefix}_#{super}"
  end
end
```

Then there is no need to define `self.table_name_prefix` in `blog.rb`.

These can be set as defaults for future models through appropriate files in `lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb` and `module.rb`, based on [the default active record templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates).

This *could* all be done by monkey-patching `ActiveRecord::Base`, but this interferes with other classes, such as `ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration`, which doesn't have a table prefix.